# variable result from sql query not showing

Tags: php, sql

Is there anything wrong in this scenario? the result isn't showing. maybe i'm getting the syntax wrong?

```
    // fetch the latest tweet
$lastTweet = '';
$q2 = "SELECT tweet FROM timel ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
list($lastTweet) = $conn->get_results($q2);



if(!$lastTweet){  
$lastTweet = "You don't have any tweets yet!";
}
var_dump($lastTweet);
```

and this on the html body:

```
<span class="latest"><strong>Latest: </strong><span id="lastTweet"><?.=$lastTweet?></span></span>
```

Comment: <?.=$lastTweet this dot?

Comment: By <?.= do you mean <?= ?

Comment: In `<?.=$lastTweet?>`, you have a `.` between `?` and `=`.  Remove it.

Comment: Didn't you forget to execute your query before getting the result?

Comment: to all: removing the dot still doesn't work though. maybe there is a another way to do this? peterm: the results are fine since i am using a class for executing queries. it works, just that i can't display the results on the html body. assuming i have no tweets yet.

Comment: @asleighna: what sql extension are you using? you also might not be able to pass the straight sql query inside the "get_results" method - http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.prepare.php

Answer (score 2):

If you changed your first line to

```
$lastTweet = array();
```

And your third line to

```
$lastTweet = $conn->get_results($q2);
```

Then you would be able to use

```
<?php var_dump($lastTweet); ?>
```

But in your case lastTweet contains a string of text, hence you need to use echo to print it's content.

```
<?php echo $lastTweet ?>
```

Nb: i'm not sure about your project details but i'm guessing you'd need to also get the date, maybe id and user_id of the tweet, if that's the case, you might want to make lastTweet an empty array()

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<span class="latest"><strong>Latest: </strong><span id="lastTweet">
<?php echo $lastTweet; ?></span>    </span>
```

Saludos ;)

Comment: okidoki. this did the trick! hmmm. so i still do have to use $echo function. thanks a bunch, Robert Rozas. and thank you for the replies, everyone. :)